# What's a more fun and creative way to say "ok"?

Tags: anglais, demande-de-mot

What's a more fun and creative way to say `ok` in the context of an web interface popup window button? In English one could say `okay`, `okey-dokey`, `roger that`, `yup`, `right on`, `sure`.

Answer (score 7):

For pop-ups about cookies privacy, **"J'ai compris !"** is very common, which is equivalent to the English "Got it!".

[image]

[image]

Some other general suggestions:

> C'est noté !
>   Compris ! (abbreviation of *J'ai compris*)
>   Bien reçu !

Answer (score 3):

Here are some suggestions:

> Pigé !
>
> Reçu cinq sur cinq !
>
> Ça marche !

Answer (score 3):

ça roule ma poule is a nice way to say you are ok with the plan.

Comment: For a web interface popup window button? Really ? Much too long.

Comment: Length-wise, «Reçu cinq sur cinq» (proposed elsewhere) is 19 characters and 5 syllables, «Ça roule ma poule» is 18 characters and 4 syllables, so the hen is shorter (at least when we dropped the pronunciation of the E's). Entertaining-wise... Well! This is a matter of taste, but I find «Reçu cinq sur cinq» a lot more formal and less colourful than «Ça roule ma poule». Plus, I also find [ɛ̃k] harsher than [ul], but this again is a matter of personal tastes.

Comment: @Feelew I agree it **is** a personal opinion my comment also applies to all proposals that are over 2 words  or 10 characters long. And for others I'd even drop the exclamation mark that takes two spaces in French.

Comment: I find it a bit old fashionned nowadays...

Answer (score 2):

D'acc (forme courte de D'accord)

Answer (score 1):

More suggestions :

- Ok d'acc' !
- Dacodac !